# CartoDB - Zoom to specific extent when clicking on a point?

Tags: javascript, css, gis, cartodb

I have a map of points, and for each of those points, a specific extent that I want the map to zoom into when I click on it.

I assume I will need to tabulate the bounds of those extents and add them as another column in the data.

Is there a way for Carto to automatically zoom to the bounds once I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to develop a CARTO.js web application. You need of course to store the bounds somehow on your table in a set of columns or in one single column using a format you can later parse. Next, you need to add that/those fields to a custom infowindow so they are passed to the web application in the interactivity. Finally, you need to listen to the feature click event in order to retrieve the interactivity data and using Leaflet map methods move its bounds.

You have all CARTO.js documentation [here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js) and a tutorial and many examples [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-workshop/blob/master/06-sdks/exercises/cartojs.md). It's easier than it seems.